# Lost my JSON media type formatters when adding custom formatter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mime-types

I'm trying to implement a CSV response from my WebAPI application if the `Accept` header has `text/csv`, but I want the "default" content type to be `application/json` (i.e., if no `Accept` header is provided, it will output JSON).

I made a simple CSV serializer:

```
public class CsvMediaTypeFormatter : OutputFormatter
{
    public CsvMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));
    }

    public override Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        var content = context.Object;
        var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        var outputStreamWriter = new StreamWriter(response.Body);
        var csvWriter = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(outputStreamWriter);
        if(content is IEnumerable)
        {
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(content as IEnumerable);
        }
        else
        {
            csvWriter.WriteRecord(content);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

... then I wired it up like so in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddOData();
services.AddMvcCore(options =>
{
    options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
    options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CsvMediaTypeFormatter());
    options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("csv", MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));
    var csvFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.OfType<CsvMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
    csvFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv"));
    foreach (var outputFormatter in options.OutputFormatters.OfType<ODataOutputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
    {
        outputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
    }
    foreach (var inputFormatter in options.InputFormatters.OfType<ODataInputFormatter>().Where(_ => _.SupportedMediaTypes.Count == 0))
    {
        inputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/prs.odatatestxx-odata"));
    }
}).AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = false });
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
})
.SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
.AddApiExplorer();
```

The OData media types already existed, and never seemed to cause any problem.

Looking at the examples I found online, this should work, but now I get a 415 error when hitting my login page that is traditionally `application/json` with a message about an unsupported media type.  Did I wipe out the "default" JSON formatter somehow?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might need to override [`OutputFormatter.CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.outputformatter.canwriteresult) as the base implementation could be returning `true`.

Comment: would that give me a 415?  I'll try it and see what happens.

Comment: According to [Format response data in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting) it's supposed to return a `406 Not Acceptable` if the client supplies an unregistered `Accept` header. But there's a list of `if` conditions involved.